# how to send data from python to hadoop on the fly

Tags: python, hadoop, web-crawler, data-mining

Hi I have python script that run on 10 machines, and mining data.
Big data...
I want to send the phrased data to hadoop cluster.
I want to install cloudera and hadoop on digitalocean.
How can Hadoop be always ready to receive files,
and than the python script will send the information with post requests with json data?
Can you suggest me any better way to send the data?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Write the data to HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a number of options:

1. Kafka + Flume. Here's an example of how this may work: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/11/flafka-apache-flume-meets-apache-kafka-for-event-processing/
2. Kafka + Spark Streaming. Try this http://www.slideshare.net/rahuldausa/real-time-analytics-with-apache-kafka-and-apache-spark and this http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/
3. In general, any queue (Kafka, RabbitMQ, AMQ, etc.) and any queue consumer that is able to write to HDFS, in the simplest case just a Java application polling queue each 30-60 seconds